# Use the First Letter of Every Word in one field to populate another field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project where I have a model called Post, and would like to create a field called post_id that is basally the first letter of every word in the post_title. So my models.py file looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
post_title = models.CharField(max_length=24)
post_id = models.CharField(max_length=24, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    output = ''
    for i in self.post_title().split():
        output += i[0]
    self.post_id= ('%s') % (output)         
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This however gives me the error:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

The error occurs at:

```
for i in self.post_title().split()
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using string formatting on `output` anyway? It's already a string.

Comment: Because I wasn't sure how to store the values.

Comment: The error is the parens after `self.post_title`.  You should always post a full stacktrace, not only the error message, which would make the error obvious, since it tells you exactly where the error is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs in this line:

```
for i in self.post_title().split():
```

what you're doing here is calling the attribute `post_title` (by using parantheses `()`) instead of simply retrieving it:

```
for i in self.post_title.split():
```

Comment: Well, not quite.  Methods are attributes as well.  `a.method()` will first retrieve the attribute `method` and then call it.  Analogously, `self.post_title()` will first retrieve the attribute `self.post_title`, which is a string, and then call it, resulting in the error message the OP got.

Comment: Wow, never thought about it that way and just learned something new today. Thank you!